# mysql : how to create a user and how to access the mysql localhost server using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to mysql and php too, so please ignore my less knowledge in this.

I want to do the following:--
1. I want to have a mysql localhost server and have a table in it in which i will keep username and password.
2. I will create a webpage with login option and once user clicks on submit then i will autenticate the user using the database i create above.

Following is what i did as of now:--
I am new to mysql and php too. I did a lot of search but was not able to understand what exactly i installed in my machine.
I downloaded mysql and installed it. I see a mysql cmd prompt. I create a database and i created a table in it.
Now how to i create a user? I tried creating it using 
CREATE user xyz;
but it says attempting to connect and connection failed (what exactly is it trying to connect?)

I did a search for accessing a localhost server and i got the code which is

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "addressbook";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);

$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {
print "Database Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
}

?>
```

which looks fairly decent to me.

My problem is how to i create a user in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

Why was i getting that error?
I installed XAMPP and started mysql server from there and i was using the command prompt of some other mysql which i have installed.

How to create a table and access it using php?
Following is what you have to do!
Install XAMPP
Once you have installed it then run "xampp-control.exe"
Start the mysql service in that controller.
Open the mysql command prompt in superuser mode using
    C:\XYZ\xampp\mysql\bin> mysql.exe -uroot

mysql shell will get open.
Create user using:
   mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';

Create Database using:
   mysql> Create DATABASE my_db;

Set the database as your current database:
   mysql> use my_db;

Create a table using:
   mysql> CREATE TABLE users
   (
   user varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   password varchar(255) NOT NULL
   );

Insert a value in that table:
   mysql> INSERT INTO users
   values ( 'usernew' , 'password' );

Now writing the php code to access this:

```
<?php

   $user_name = "newuser";
   $password = "mypass";
   $database = "my_db";
   $server = "localhost";
   $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die(mysql_error());
   $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle) or die(mysql_error());

   if ($db_found) {
   print "Database Found ";
   }

   else {
   print "Database NOT Found ";
   }

   $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
   $result = mysql_query($query);

   while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
         foreach ($line as $value)
          {
            print "$value\n";
        }
         }

      $queryInsert = "INSERT INTO users values('mohan', 'mohan123')";
      $result = mysql_query($queryInsert);

      mysql_close($db_handle);

?>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

You can see how to create a user, and from there also links on granting rights or at least limiting what they can/cant do.

Comment: I tried that but i get this
    mysql> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
    No connection. Trying to reconnect...
    ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'admin'
I dont know why its tring to access database 'admin'
    ERROR:
    Can't connect to the server

Comment: It maybe you dont have rights to create users and you have to do it through an area your webhoster provides..

Comment: am not very sure if i got you right. can you please help me in sorting this out?

Comment: Is the mySQL on your local PC which you control, or a hosted one?

Comment: Id suggest you use phpmySql to check its working, as it doesnt sound like its properly connecting etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13442/discussion-between-ankitg-and-bugfinder)

Answer (score 1):

Small Hint: use this for development

```
 $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password) or die(mysql_error());
 $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle) or die(mysql_error());
```

In Case the connection fail or the select you get throw the die(mysql_error()) detail informations from your dbms what the error is

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I will definetly try this out.
But right now am not even able to create a user in the mysql database.
I tried this 
mysql> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'admin'

I dont know why its tring to access database 'admin' ERROR: Can't connect to the server

Answer (score 1):

You also may install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), which is a set of Apache, PHP, MySQL Server and PhpMyadmin. It will help you to start working with MySQL and PHP.

After starting services, you will be able to create new user in MySQL console, or in the PhpMyadmin.

Comment: I have installed XAMPP and i have started mysql service in that. But I have installed mysql again using a installer and am using the command shell of that mysql.
While trying to create a user am facing this issue
 mysql> CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'admin'
ERROR: Can't connect to the server 
I dont know why its tring to access database 'admin'.

Comment: Hm, stange error. The MySQL server is started, then you connect using console, all is OK. Right? Then you write in the console CREATE USER and get error 'no connection...'.

Comment: i think i got the problem.. i have installed xampp and mysql seperately... and i mixed it up somewhere

Comment: You can use two MySQL servers together. Only specify different ports, the default is 3306. Change it in my.ini file and restart server.